# Help installing fedora13 from DvD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, installation, fedora-13

I have windows xp on my dell but I lost the drivers disk so I want to install linux Fedora 13 instead and wipe the windows xp.

I burned the iso to a dvd and loaded up the live session user and used "Install to harddrive" but when I get to the partitioning window there is no harddrives to install to so I cant overwrite the windows drive (/C:)..

Help?

Comment: removing [osx] tag since this doesn't appear to have anything to do with Mac OS X.

Comment: Can't you download the XP drivers from Dell's website if you lost the drivers disk? If drivers are the only reason you are shifting away from Windows, you should try this.

Comment: No. Its not just the drivers I want to have linux. 

and osx must have slipped in there when i meant "OS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try a liveCD first. Ubuntu for example. Write it out / copy it to a pendrive. Boot it, and check your partitions by opening a terminal and typing:
`sudo gparted`

Here you can create a new partition table. (**You'll lose all your data!**). Try creating one ext2 partition for example which covers the whole HDD. (In the Fedora installer you'll make your partition setup what you want, this is only for the sake of being detected.)

Comment: Or a Fedora Live CD. Those do exist.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But I don't know if it comes with gparted. Ubuntu is easier in this aspect (and they have the same size.)

Comment: I'll try this. downloading the ubununtu iso now!

Comment: Also, if Fedora is not the ONLY way, then if you try with Fedora and it won't work, just install Ubuntu. (Or try openSUSE if you hate Ubuntu for some reason.)

Comment: Ok Shiki, 

I used gparted and formated the space it was ntfs, so maybe it needs to be ms-dos to be reconnized. Anyway I now have a working installations of ubuntu thanks to you!!!!!

Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @user38008: Hehe okay. If you have any question (and want it to be solved fast), come to #Ubuntu IRC channel on Freenode IRC network.